# Get last status

Tags: sql

I have table:

[image]

I want to get the latest status for today, provided that if there are no vacations or business trips on the current date, the "Job" status should be displayed. I use this query, but it's incorrect (some times it shows two values)

```
SELECT Name,Status,Start,End
  FROM employee as emp
  Where Start = (Select max(Start) from employee  as emp2 where emp.Name = emp2.Name )
 Order by Name
```

Current result

```
Name     Status        Start     End
People-1 Job           2/3/2020  0001-01-01 00:00:00.000
People-1 business trip 4/20/2022 4/22/2022
```

Expected result:

```
Name     Status        Start    End
People-1 Job           2/3/2020 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Show us the current result and also the expected result. (Use formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: If it shows more then 1 row in result that means that the rows in the result have exactly the same value in column `start` (same date, hour, minute, second). If you want 1 row as a result you need to specify the criteria to selects 1 row rather then others, what is that other criteria?

Comment: the criterion is as follows if the current date (today) does not fall within the period where the end column is not equal to 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000, then output the status in which the end column is equal to 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000. Otherwise, the status is displayed from the period where the date falls

Comment: I find your current result a bit unexpected. Can you create a fiddle, so we can reproduce? https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to fully understand your desired behaviour but assuming the following is true this sql should work:

1. There are multiple 'employee' records in the table
2. You want all records for all employees which match the following

   - the start date must be the most recent date in the data set (this is not the same as saying the start date must equal today's date)
   - the status must not be vacation or business trip.

```
create temporary table employees (
  start date,
  name varchar,
  status varchar
);

insert into employees (start, name, status) values
('2022-05-03', 'Adam', 'vacation'),
('2022-05-03', 'Bill', 'business_trip'),
('2022-05-05', 'Adam', 'business_trip'),
('2022-05-05', 'Bill', 'Job'),
('2022-05-05', 'Wendy', 'Job');

select * from employees
where start = ( select max(start) from employees) AND
( status != 'vacation' AND status != 'business_trip' );

   start    | name  | status
------------+-------+--------
 2022-05-05 | Bill  | Job
 2022-05-05 | Wendy | Job
```

Its very close to what you posted though so I'm not quite sure why you are getting multiple results for the data set you shared.I'd go back and double check your data set and confirm the sql query you shared is in fact the one you used to produce the output.

Hope that helps or at least provides some inspiration to fix your problem.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe the conditions exactly, I'm sorry. I need to get the employee status for today, if today's date does not fall into any period (the start and end columns), then I need to show the status whose end column is equal to 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000